# Umbraco for beginners: Setup Umbraco on localhost together with VS 2012 and uSiteBuilder

Tags: .net, iis, visual-studio-2012, umbraco

**Introduction**

Spent last two days trying to get Umbraco to work with visual studio 2012,iis and some kind of pagebuilder. After following lots of guides including Umbraco 5 to later find out that Umbraco 5 is dead i got it to work.

I am only doing this to help new Umbraco users like myself to get a good start in their developement.

**Setup Umbraco With VS 2012**

1. Create a new WebForm Project from the installed VS 2012 Templates.
2. Remove everything from the solution except Properties and References.
3. From Package Manager Console run "PM > Install-Package UmbracoCms"
4. Rightclick on the Project and select Properties. Under the WebTab make sure the project uses Local IIS Web Server and "Create Virtual Directory".
5. Save Project and run with F5. VS 2012 Asks if you wold like to modify Web.config file for debugging, click OK.
6. Now follow the Umbraco installationssteps from your webbrowser.
7. On Database Configuration, choose 'SQL CE 4 database'.
8. On starterkits choose empty template.
9. First step completed. Now we just need to add uSiteBuilder to our project.

**Setup uSiteBuilder to be able to easily build DocumentTypes and Templates etcetera from Code**

10. Download uSiteBuilder.dll from http://usitebuilder.codeplex.com/releases/view/71768
11. Add a reference to this dll in References inside your VS 2012 Project
12. Copy uSiteBuilder.dll to the binfolder inside your project.
13. Push F5, you will notice that the dll will add a reference to our dll in the web.config
14. Follow uSiteBuilder guides below to build DocumentTypes(ordinary .cs classes) and Templates(master and nested masterpages)

*DocumentTypes* - http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/tutorials?id=22389

*Templates*  - http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/tutorials?id=22391

**Finished**

When we have done all these steps we are ready to build Umbracosites from code with the help of uSiteBuilder.

- Since we only downloaded the uSiteBuilder.dll and not the whole package with included vs2012 templates we have to add the classes(DocumentTypes) and Masterpages(Templates) ourselves.

Comment: You should put this up on the wiki over at our.umbraco.com

Comment: Good idea, will do that!

Comment: Its fine you're doing this, but you're doing it wrong.  Your question must *ask a question*, which you can then answer below with the details.  So please [edit] to turn this into a quesiton (e.g., Need to set up Umbraco, here are my requirements, here are pitfalls I have faced, how can I do this?) then flag to have it reopened.  After reopening, you can add your answer, then accept it after the required waiting period.