# Setting up Umbraco project with nuget in vs 2012 error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, umbraco

I'm trying to set up a development project in vs 2012 with nuget and Umbraco. I am aware of the several recipe's, amongst the better  [Umbraco for beginners: Setup Umbraco on localhost together with VS 2012 and uSiteBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157983/umbraco-for-beginners-setup-umbraco-on-localhost-together-with-vs-2012-and-usit).

When I am using this procedure I install Umbraco with nuget and build it without problems, but when I hit F5 I get the same error continously: "Could not load type Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" which global.asax inherits from!

What is wrong, what am I missing here...? Thanks in advance /Finn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems like an unprofessional oversight from my point! I just forgot to give security access to the relevant folders to network service.

You might have to build and clean the solution a couple of times if you get exposed to the YSOD error: "Cannot create/shadow copy 'filename' when that file already exists" when you hit F5! This error might occur if you hit F5 too quickly after a build, in this case asp.net is probably not finished with whatever it has to complete, and the file is locked.

@Digbyswift: I do not agree with you! Whether you set up your project as an MVC or Webforms application, it doesn't matter. What is important though, is that you use empty applications, as if you don't there will probably be some references/dependencies that you have to delete in order to get the application running! And default server will be the vs dev server, which in my opinion is by far the best and easiest to use untill you are ready to deploy your application. I agree thouhg that using the package-manager from visual studio is the easiest way to come around installing Umbraco.

Following these steps and hints you should use no more than a couple of minutes from installing Umbraco untill you have the wellcome screen and is ready to set up db etc...

Cheers Finn...

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I had the same problem and the reason for that are missing dll's. Referenced libraries weren't copied to bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best or easiest way of setting the project up.

Instead of creating a WebForm project, create an empty MVC4 project and then install the Umbraco CMS from NuGet. This way you won't have to remove anything. It will also by default use IIS Express, so there is no need to change the project properties.

You don't even have to use the NuGet console. You can use the package manager and just search for Umbraco.